# Convert date format to different date format in android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

In my application i want to change date format. In my application getting the date like this **04/07/20**. But in my application I want to display like this **07, April 20**. For that I using the following code

```
try {
       String date="04/07/20"
       SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy")
       Date newDate = spf.parse(date);
       SimpleDateFormat new_spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yy");
       date = new_spf.format(newDate);
        System.out.println(date);
      } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

But the output getting like this **07 January, 20**, But I need **07 April, 20**.

Can you share the suggestions for this one.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your requirement nd your result seems similar! How you want the result? Whats the difference in Jan and April dates?

Comment: here getting January instead of April. The actual date is 04/07/20 if I changed the date format date should be 07 April, 20, but the output getting 07 January, 20.

Comment: Month displaying wrong

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You mixed:

```
mm  =  minutes
```

with

```
MM  =  months
```

## So you have to change from:

```
SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy");
```

in to:

```
SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```

When you print before changes:

```
System.out.println(newDate);
```

You will receive:

```
 Tue Jan 07 00:04:00 WET 2020
               /\
               ||
               ||
          your minutes
```

## Full working example

(with better naming)

```
try {
    String inputDate = "04/07/20";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    Date parsedDate = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yy");

    inputDate = outputFormat.format(parsedDate);
    System.out.println(inputDate);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```